# Is euclidean heuristic function consistent in a road network graph?

Tags: algorithm, a-star

In a road network graph, the nodes are represented by their coordinates *(x,y)* and the edges have a weight equal to the euclidean distance between the two connected nodes.

In an A* search algorithm executed over a road network graph, is the heuristic defined as the euclidean distance consistent (*h(m)<=h(n)+d(m,n)* for any edge *(m,n)*)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Euclidean distance heuristic is consistent.  This property is known as the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)

It also works on the [surface of the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_geometry), if you use great-circle distances, even though that geometry is non-Euclidean.

Be careful to do it correctly, though -- calculating with latitude and longitude as if they were cartesian coordinates can sometimes produce the wrong answer.